# mail can't send messages: Process exited with a non-zero status

Tags: linux, bash, email

I wrote a bash script that sends out a mail, but after 50 e-mails it starts to say "mail can't send messages: Process exited with a non-zero status". Can anyone help solve my problem. The code I used is below if you want to take a look at it.

```
#!/bin/bash

#Declare variables area.

emailBody=email_body.txt; #you have to use without “ symbol for some reason
emailList=email_list_delimiter.txt;

#send mail command. using a read file loop.

while IFS= read -r emailTo; do
    cat $emailBody |
    mail -s "Hi, I'm looking for a position in IT Field." $emailTo |
    echo “Success”;
done < <(grep . $emailList)
```

Comment: `“”` aren't valid programming quotes. While bash/echo will simply treat them as plaintext here, you shoudln't be using a wordprocessor to edit your code.

Comment: that's what bash script is. bashscript allow you to use linux command. that's the whole purpose of bash doing repeative task like e-mailing. You think removing the echo command will remove that non-zero status?

Answer (score 0):

You are probably hitting a server-side limit on the number of messages you can send in a fixed time, or equivalently the number of connections allowed within a moving window of time.

If you can (the message is not "personalized") it is best to send *one* message to multiple recipients, rather than many messages, each to one recipient. Do that by perhaps putting your own e-mail address in the `To` field, and then `Bcc`ing the whole of the list of recipients in one go. You'll have to check your mail command for how to do that.

Comment: https://support.google.com/a/answer/166852?hl=en  there could be a limit. Trying to figure out if I need to change a setting in google email.

Comment: I suspect Google won't let you change such a limit. It's there to stop you flooding their servers. But if you can send just *one* message with all those recipients, it will take a fraction of the time of sending enough messages to annoy Google....

Comment: I look thru the settings to try to change the limit. I probally need to develope a way to send a limit amount each day of 500 mail before send another 500 next day or a week later.